# @Transactional for Native queries does not worK

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

Consider following code:

```
class ClassOne {
      @Autowired
      ClassTwo classTwo;

      public void mainMethod() {
          Query query = em.createNativeQuery(...);
          classTwo.runTransaction(query);
     }
}

@Component
class ClassTwo {
    @Transactional
    public void runTransaction(Query) {
        System.err.println(TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

When running the `mainMethod`, I am getting following exception:

```
Executing an update/delete query javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor103.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:310)
at $Proxy55.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at ...ClassTwo.runTransaction(...)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at ...ClassOne.mainMethod(...)
```

I find it strange that it compains about the missing transaction, even if you can clearly see in the stacktrace, that it passed through `TransactionInterceptor`.

Also the `isActualTransactionAlive` returns true.

Comment: You should also create the query inside the transactional method. You cannot create a query on a non-transactional entitymanager and then magically expect it to participate in a transaction later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get Query object within transaction context. Currently, its outside transaction context. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I've just found it out. It surprises me a bit, I've found several examples, which say this should be possible.